# Dynamyc queries in knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to implement unions that can dynamically take query strings or builder as parameters. See the code below:

```js
function dynamicUnion(queryString||builder){
baseQuery.union(function () {
//I want to use query string or querybuilder  here instead.
     this.select('*').from('users').whereNull('first_name');
        })
     }
```

In the place of the line: `this.select('*').from('users').whereNull('first_name')`, I would like to implement something like: `this.raw(queryString||builder)` or any working alternative though I've not come across `.raw()` method when working with `this` keyword in that block.

I am implementing it this way since the `select` queries that are to be used in the `union` will will vary and it's efficient if passed dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in knex that `this.raw` is not working in this case. Here is one way to pass raw query to union:

```
const Knex = require('knex');


const knex = Knex({
  client: 'mysql',
});

knex('foo').union(knex.raw('foo bar')).toSQL();

// outputs "select * from `foo` union foo bar"
```

https://runkit.com/embed/10boda0lt1it

Comment: YES, `union()` can take a builder as a param but not documented. `this()` also should.

Comment: in knex query builder should be allowed parameter to pretty much everywhere (sadly there are still lots of inconsistencies in API regarding that)